# RestClient basic auth with # in username

Tags: ruby, basic-authentication, rest-client

I have a problem with a daemon accessing a REST api.

The access requires basic authentication. The username and password are fixed and can not be changed.

The problem seems to be, that the username looks like this: `#ws+R4nd0mS7r1n`

I access the API like this:

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new( "#{base_url}/failover/#{failover_ip}", { :user => user_name, :password => user_password})
response = resource.get
```

This gets me an bad URI error:

```
bad URI(absolute but no path): https://#ws+R4nd0mS7r1n:RaNdOmPaSsWoRd@robot-ws.your-server.de/failover/11.11.11.11
```

When I itentionally remove the # from the username it works, but I get a NOT Authenticated error.

Is there a way to pass a username or password containing # to restclient?
Passing the complete URI manually to a .get does not work either.

Comment: Have u tried any other clients? Like [faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) or [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/delicious.rb) ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `#` with `%23`?

Comment: The username/password combination eventually makes its way into the Authorization header part of the http request, so Oto's suggestion of trying an alternative client is sound. Also, you might try setting the header directly

Comment: I tried HTTParty but now I get errors like "Cannot convert HTTParty.Response to String". Is there a way to easily do this, so that I dont have to adapt the whole application?

Comment: See my answer below - what version of Ruby and rest-client are you using? It's also likely that rest-client is using a deeper http transport library, and it is that which is rejecting the URI. You probably don't need to re-tool, just find the component that is out-of-date or incompatible with your required service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get the same error. What version of `rest-client` do you have installed?

You may simply be able to update the version to fix your problem (I tested with version 1.6.7 of the gem)

Alternatively, this works around the URI failure by directly writing to the Authorization header (which is where this data ends up anyway):

```
require 'base64'
auth = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode64( "#{user_name}:#{user_password}" ).chomp
resource = RestClient::Resource.new( "#{base_url}/failover/#{failover_ip}", { :headers => { 'Authorization' => auth } } )
resource.get
```

Comment: I'm using 1.6.7 too, with ruby 1.8.

Comment: I tried 1.6.7 and ruby 1.8.7-p352, and got a connection to an echo service, which showed the auth header being set as follows: `Authorization: Basic I3dzK1I0bmQwbVM3cjFuOmZvbw==` . . . so I suspect you have something else in the call stack failing. I'll try to figure out a work-around for you

Comment: Put a work-around into my answer. You may still wish to check your network stack for what is throwing the error - it could just be an out-of-date gem somewhere.

Comment: I tried that and it seemed to be working. Switched to an other API in the END.